# What is the best way to handle updates after a user stops typing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component form and I'm passing and updateDraft function once the user stops typing. Is this the best way to handle it?

```
const updateTimer = (props) => {
    if (this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        props.updateDraft
    }, 5000)
};

    const Form = (props) => {

        return(
            <Input type="text" 
    onKeyUp={updateTimer(props)} 
    onChange={props.onChange} 
    />
        )

    }
```

Comment: Asking for "the best way" is asking for opinionated answer.  Rather than phrasing your question in such a way, state the problem, and ask for solutions.  Let the answers respond with what they think are valid solutions, and then **you** get you choose which you think is the best.

Comment: Just add a submit button and only handle the inputted data if the button is clicked. This route makes it easier for you as a programmer as well as for the user who might still want to input more data but pauses to think. However, if you are talking about real-time rendering functionalities like an autocomplete dropdown or something like that, just use `onchange` and push each key entered to a state property then handle the data in the state whenever there is a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onblur` - when user exits form. If there is not much to do by your function, you can easily use `onchange`, `onkeyup`. As @AndrewL mentioned you can also add button, but either of those solutions are porbably better then setting up a timeout.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about onBlur